# Handling together marker click and doubleclick on googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following problem.
On my google map app I need to distinguish click and doulbe click on the markers.

So when I am creating markers I create two listeners:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerTMP, 'click', (function(routeID) {
                return function() {
                    console.log('click '+routeID);
                }
            })(pointRoute));

google.maps.event.addListener(markerTMP, 'dblclick', (function(routeID) {
                return function() {
                    p('double click '+routeID);
                }
            })(pointRoute));
```

The problem is that when I use double click, click is also used.
My idea how to handle this:
On click - create a timeout, on double click - delete it.

But is there a normal way to handle this?
I was not able to found it in API reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "official" way to handle this in the API. Creating a timeout seems to be the [accepted approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329136/handling-click-events-in-google-maps-js-api-v3-while-ignoring-double-clicks).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workaround. it uses a global var to work across the two functions. Not the most eloquent, but works.

```
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    x = 0
                    update_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        if (x == 0) {
                            // do something ;
                        };
                    }, 300);   
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
                    x=1
                    // do something ;
                });
```

Comment: This works well. Pretty cheesy that it must be this way, but c'est la vie. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try using a click event and a rightclick event instead of click and dblclick.