# Google maps api v3 - Map Toolbar implementation - settimeout for dblclick zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, settimeout

I use Map Toolbar implementation for javascript Google maps api v3:
http://nettique.free.fr/gmap/toolbar.html

It's working great! My only matter is that I wanna keep the dblclick event to zoom while creating a polygon, but now, if I double-click, I create a new marker and delete it right away.

With an older version of my code, I was using a timeout like explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417447/1895428

but now, no matter where I put the setTimeout function, it makes no change. Does anybody knows where to put it?

I tried to modify the addPoint function in the js code (http://nettique.free.fr/gmap/lib/mapToolbar.js), but it didn't work:

```
addPoint : function(e, poly, index) { //alert(MapToolbar["shapeCounter"]);
        update_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        var e = (typeof e.latLng != "undefined")? e.latLng : e,
            image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/image/marker-edition.png',
            new google.maps.Size(9, 9),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(5, 5)),
        imageover = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/image/marker-edition-over.png',
            new google.maps.Size(9, 9),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(5, 5)),
                path = poly.getPath(),
                index = (typeof index != "undefined")? index : path.length,
                markers = (poly.markers)? poly.markers : new google.maps.MVCArray, 
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: e,
                    map: map[mapkey],
                    draggable: true,
                    icon: image
        });

        marker.index = index;    
        path.insertAt(index, e);
        markers.insertAt(index, marker)
        if(arguments[2]){
            MapToolbar.reindex(markers);    
        } }, 200);

//click on a polymarker will delete it

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.setMap(null);
            markers.removeAt(marker.index);
            path.removeAt(marker.index);
            MapToolbar.reindex(markers);                
            if(markers.getLength() == 0){
                MapToolbar.removeFeature(poly.id);
            }
        });

/*
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
                MapToolbar.currentlyDragging = true;
        })
*/      
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function() {
              path.setAt(marker.index, marker.getPosition());
        })

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                //MapToolbar.currentlyDragging = false;
            path.setAt(marker.index, marker.getPosition());
            var position = marker.getPosition(),
                    p;

//get previous point

            if(typeof path.getAt(marker.index-1) != "undefined"){
                var m1 = path.getAt(marker.index -1);
                        p = MapToolbar.getMidPoint(position, m1);       
                        MapToolbar.addPoint(p, poly, marker.index);                     
            }

// get next point

            if(typeof path.getAt(marker.index+1) != "undefined"){
                var m2 = path.getAt(marker.index+1);
                        p = MapToolbar.getMidPoint(position, m2);       
                        MapToolbar.addPoint(p, poly, marker.index+1);                       
            }           
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                this.setIcon(imageover);
        });   

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                this.setIcon(image);
        }); 

        MapToolbar["isStarted"]++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but following the stackoverflow example you have to change only listener code:

```
addPoint : function(e, poly, index) {
    var e = (typeof e.latLng != "undefined")? e.latLng : e,
    ...

//click on a polymarker will delete it

    var update_timeout = null;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        update_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            marker.setMap(null);
            markers.removeAt(marker.index);
            path.removeAt(marker.index);
            MapToolbar.reindex(markers);                
            if(markers.getLength() == 0){
                MapToolbar.removeFeature(poly.id);
            }
        }, 200);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function(event) {       
        clearTimeout(update_timeout);
    });
    ...
```

Comment: Still not working... Anyway, this click event is to remove a marker if you click on it, I was more looking for a timeout set on the addPoint event.