# alternatives on mobile device to rightclick

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have read here that the alternative to detecting a non-mobile device (left) `click` event on a Google-maps marker is to detect a `mousedown` event on a mobile device. What alternatives to detecting a non-mobile device `righclick` event are available? Is there a way to detect a doubletap or some other touch event in an event Listener?

Comment: You can always use the `mouseup` event. For double clicks, just use any event and store the time each click happened in a global object. If the last time recorded isn't `undefined` and is within 200ms of the current event time, it should be counted as a double click.

Comment: [This link seems to suggest ways to handle your 200ms suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329136/). I am unclear about your reference to `mouseup`. Do you mean instead of `mousedown` or do you mean in connection with double-click? Please clarify. Also, do you know if mobile devices accept mousedown/up and dblclick?

Comment: Nevermind. I think I have what I need after experimenting on jsfiddle.net . It appears that double taps on an iOS device triggers double-click in google-maps. That together with the link I posted in my previous comment will likely satisfy my needs.